# A question about independent rvs and expectation. 

Tags: probability

Let $X$, $Y$ be independent random variables, $E\left(\left|X\right|^p\right)<+\infty$ where $p\geq 1$ and $E(Y)=0$. Show that $E\left(\left|X+Y\right|^p\right)\geq E(\left|X\right|^p)$, where $E\left(\cdot\right)$ stands for expectation.

Comment: @Srivatsan: you're right, there wasn't that typo before I edited it for the first time.

Comment: Thank you for your hint.I didn`t think of jensen inequality before.

Comment: @cheng: If you have a proof, you could write it yourself as an answer, wait a reasonable amount of time to see whether people agree with it, then *accept* your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: for every fixed $x$ and every random variable $Y$, $E(|x+Y|^p)≥|x+E(Y)|^p$.

Jensen's inequality seems to be the way to prove this, hence the first goal is to find a convex function somewhere... Once you know this, the rest should be easy.

Comment: Do you mean integrate with respect to x?but we won`t get E|X+Y|^p on the left side ,but an iterated integration.

Comment: Sorry? Call $u(x)=E(|x+Y|^p)$, then $E(u(X))=E(|X+Y|^p)$. This is a consequence of the independence of $X$ and $Y$ (hence the distribution of $(X,Y)$ is a product distribution) and of Fubini's theorem.

Comment: @cheng, any further question on this solution?